# Dynamically added method invisible to hasattr() in a subclass

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have an issue with a dynamically added method to a Python class. Consider the following set of classes with methods `<some>_str` added dynamically for any defined `<some>` method.

```
class ToStr(object):
    @classmethod
    def add_str_method(cls, name):
        method = getattr(cls, name)
        def str_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return str(method(*args, **kwargs))
        setattr(cls, '{0}_str'.format(name), str_method)

class Even(ToStr):
    @classmethod
    def even(cls, values):
        return [value for value in values if value%2 == 0]
Even.add_str_method('even')

class Large(ToStr):
    @classmethod
    def large(cls, values):
        filtered = [value for value in values if value > 5]
        if hasattr(cls, 'even'):
            filtered = cls.even(filtered)
        return filtered
Large.add_str_method('large')

class Special(Even, Large):
    pass
```

Note that dynamically added `%_str` functions are instance methods, while `%` are class methods. Also the `large` method depends on the existence of `even` method, which is determined by `hasattr(cls, 'even')`.

Now I compare output of `%` and `%_str` methods in each of the classes, and results are confusing to me:

```
# Even.even
Even().even(values)          [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
Even().even_str(values)      [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
# Large.large
Large().large(values)        [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Large().large_str(values)    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# Special.even
Special().even(values)       [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
Special().even_str(values)   [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
# Special.large
Special().large(values)      [6, 8, 10]
Special().large_str(values)  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The `Special.large_str()` method doesn't remove even values, although the `Special` class should inherit it from the `Even` class, passing the `hasattr` check.

So my question is: **Why aren't these methods identified by `hasattr` when adding methods dynamically?**

---

**UPDATE:**

This effect does not depend on the order of super-classes in the `Special` class definitions.
This effect does NOT happen if the `even` and `large` methods are defined as instance methods, instead of class methods, like in the example below.

```
class ToStr(object):
    @classmethod
    def add_str_method(cls, name):
        method = getattr(cls, name)
        def str_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return str(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
        setattr(cls, '{0}_str'.format(name), str_method)

class Even(ToStr):
    def even(self, values):
        return [value for value in values if value%2 == 0]
Even.add_str_method('even')

class Large(ToStr):
    def large(self, values):
        filtered = [value for value in values if value > 5]
        if hasattr(self, 'even'):
            filtered = self.even(filtered)
        return filtered

Large.add_str_method('large')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case is that `classmethod`s can be called on a class so when you do `getattr` of a `classmethod` on the class it will be a bound method (the first argument is already filled in). That means that you'll add methods that remember the class you used in `getattr`. Therefore the call to `Special().large_str(values)` will call `str_method` but the `method` call inside will just call `Large.large` with `cls=Large` but `Large` itself has no `even` method.

On the other hand not-`classmethods` will return a free function in `getattr` and therefore the first argument won't be fixed, that's why you needed to include the `self` parameter in the `method`-call in your `str_method` in your second approach.

```
class ToStr(object):
    @classmethod
    def add_str_method(cls, name):
        method = getattr(cls, name)
        def str_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(method)                          # added a print!
            return str(method(*args, **kwargs))
        setattr(cls, '{0}_str'.format(name), str_method)

class Even(ToStr):
    @classmethod
    def even(cls, values):
        return [value for value in values if value%2 == 0]
Even.add_str_method('even')

class Large(ToStr):
    @classmethod
    def large(cls, values):
        print(cls)                             # added a print!
        filtered = [value for value in values if value > 5]
        if hasattr(cls, 'even'):
            filtered = cls.even(filtered)
        return filtered
Large.add_str_method('large')

class Special(Even, Large):
    pass
```

illustrates this behaviour:

```
>>> Special().large_str(list(range(11)))             
<bound method Large.large of <class '__main__.Large'>>    # bound method
<class '__main__.Large'>                                  # wrong cls

'[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]'                                        # wrong result
```

while the normal method variant prints:

```
<function Large.large at 0x0000024B2FE808C8>       # free function
<__main__.Special object at 0x0000024B2FE7C3C8>    # correct instance

'[6, 8, 10]'                                       # correct result
```

---

A possible solution/workaround *in your case* would be to call the wrapped function in your `str_method` (in this case that will return the unbound method):

```
class ToStr(object):
    @classmethod
    def add_str_method(cls, name):
        method = getattr(cls, name)
        def str_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return str(method.__func__(self, *args, **kwargs))  # this line changed
        setattr(cls, '{0}_str'.format(name), str_method)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was not obvious to me. But is there a way to overcome this, maintaining class methods? In this particular example it doesn't make sense, but I have an analogous situation in Django framework, were I need to define class methods by hand, and dynamically add instance methods.

Comment: @BartoNaz try using metaclasses or class decorators instead. I think you wouldn't run into this problem in that case.

Comment: @BartoNaz Good question. The simplest solution (if you only deal with `classmethod`s) would be to call `return str(method.__func__(self, *args, **kwargs))` in `str_method`. The `__func__` returns the unbound method so it should work correctly, but then you can't call `large_str` on classes, it's just possible for instances. All other approaches require non-trivial solutions like metaclasses, class decorators, or an own implementation of `classmethod` (and should be asked in a new question because you only asked "Why aren't these methods identified by hasattr when adding methods dynamically?")

Comment: And without an actual use-case it's pretty hard to give a specific solution. Generic solutions for such problems are really complicated.

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks! This works perfectly! And shouldn't the `large_str` method only be called on instances anyway? I don't see how your solution is limiting my original implementation. Or do you mean, that it is in principle impossible to dynamically add inheritable class methods with this approach?

Comment: @BartoNaz I was only enumerating the limitations of the `method.__func__` solution. If that works for you that's great. I actually don't quite understand the "dynamically add inheritable class methods". So I'm probably not able to answer on that score :)

Comment: @MSeifert Ok. Then could you please update your answer with the `__func__` solution, or add it as a new answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @BartoNaz Ok, I added that to the answer :)